# Adding new items to Combo Box when the user clicks on it

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Combo box which lists recipe names. The recipes are kept in a directory. When the user clicks on the combo, I need to add/delete items and display the new new drop down list. Which event can I use for updating the list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would prefer following way. Add a ObservableCollection of your recipes to the class members:

```
ObservableCollection<Recipe> recipeList = new ObservableCollection<Recipe>();
```

Set the data source of your combo box and subscribe the Click EventHandler:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = recipeList;
comboBox1.Click += new EventHandler(comboBox1_Click);
```

In the click handler of the combobox you can add items to the list and "by magic" (due to the observable pattern) items will be shown in the combobox

```
void comboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    recipeList.Add(new Recipe { Name = "Spagetti Bolognese" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ComboBox Selected Index Changed event but make sure you have a default value when loading the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the combo box in winform editor (or add an event handler for SelectedIndexChanged) and you should get something like

```
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
    }
```

That will be fired everytime a user selects an item, then you can modify the items with `comboBox1.Items.Add("test");` or something like that.

If you meant that everytime you click on the combo box the list is changed, you can take advantage of the Click event. Go to properties (of the combobox) and then events, and double click on Click.
 [image: example]

That should generate code that will automatically fire whenever the component is clicked.